# reverse proxy example.com/cn to cn.example.com

Tags: php, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, redirection

I have one joomla website on amazon linux2 with apache and php 7.4 as **example.com** and i am managing languages with plugin, like if i open **example.com/cn** it opens in chinese language and **example.com/fr** opens in french language.

it works if i open **cn.example.com/cn** and **fr.example.com/fr** but not as expected **cn.example.com**, **fr.example.com**

Here is my apache vhost configuration file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName cn.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/cn.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/cn.example.com-access_log" common
     ProxyRequests Off
           <Proxy *>
     Order deny,allow
           Allow from all
     </Proxy>
         ProxyPass /  http://cn.example.com/cn/
</VirtualHost>
```

Any other approach will be appreciated

Comment: Should't that be `ProxyPass /  http://example.com/cn/`?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider main domain is pointed on different server, but i tried this also. no luck.